# Compute hashCode for OR logic

Tags: java, logic, equals, hashcode

I have an object acting as a unique identifier, that has two parameters, we'll call them A and B, and has the following logic:

obj1 is equal to obj2 if and only if:

```
obj1.A is equal to obj2.A
```

*OR*

```
obj1.B is equal to obj2.B
```

How can I compute a contractually satisfactory hashCode() for this object?  Am I stuck doing the horribly inefficient solution of "return 0 always"?  Not sure what kind of math to do here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `equals` method isn't transitive. It doesn't respect one of the [basic principles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) :

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null
>   object references:
>
> It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x)
>   should return true. It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values
>   x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x)
>   returns true.
>
> It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x,
>   y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true,
>   then x.equals(z) should return true.
>
> It is consistent: for any
>   non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y)
>   consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no
>   information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified. For
>   any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

This "equality" logic makes your object unsuitable as keys and you can't fix that by simply devising a `hashCode` method,

Don't make this an `equals` method but use your own semantic, like for example `isEquivalentTo`.

Comment: Well that was rather silly of me.  Good catch, looks like I need to brush up on my basics a bit.  So, I won't be able to use a unique key like I thought.